# error in box averaging filter of an image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I need to downsize an image using a box averaging filter , I tried to write this code but there was an error : `Unknown command option.` , where is the error and what is the correct algorithm for box filter i know the idea of it ,the new pixel = averaging the four neighboring pixels . 
the code:

```
clear, clc

image=imread('p128.jpg');
old_size=size(image);
out_image=zeros(old_size(1)/2 , old_size(2)/2);

for i = 1 : old_size(1) - 1
    for j= 1 : old_size(2) - 1
        for k= i : i+1
            for t= j : j+1 
                out_image(k,t)=(image(i,j)+image(i+1,j)+image(i,j+1)+...
                    image(i+1,j+1))/4 ;
            end
        end
    end
end

figure(1), imshow(out_image)
```

Comment: in which line do you have that error? Matlab usually says which line produces the error, this is a startpoint for debugging

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`im2cols` with `'distinct'`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/im2col.html)** from Image Processing Toolbox to re-arrange the windows elements into columns and then calculate the average of each column, which would represent the average of each window. Now, in the comments you said you don't want to use any function from IP toolbox, so we have replaced `im2cols` with our own custom made implementation. Thus, assuming `im` to be the input grayscale image data, you can use this -

```
box_len = 2; %// length of the box
im_cols = im2col_distinct(im,[box_len box_len]);
im_downsized = uint8(reshape(mean(im_cols,1),size(im,1)/box_len,[]));
```

Associated function -

```
function out = im2col_distinct(A,blocksize)

nrows = blocksize(1);
ncols = blocksize(2);
nele = nrows*ncols;

row_ext = mod(size(A,1),nrows);
col_ext = mod(size(A,2),ncols);

padrowlen = (row_ext~=0)*(nrows - row_ext);
padcollen = (col_ext~=0)*(ncols - col_ext);

A1 = zeros(size(A,1)+padrowlen,size(A,2)+padcollen);
A1(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2)) = A;

t1 = reshape(A1,nrows,size(A1,1)/nrows,[]);
t2 = reshape(permute(t1,[1 3 2]),size(t1,1)*size(t1,3),[]);
t3 =  permute(reshape(t2,nele,size(t2,1)/nele,[]),[1 3 2]);
out = reshape(t3,nele,[]);

return;
```

Thus, you would be avoiding all that messy nested loops with your original code.

Input :

[image]

Output :

[image]

Comment: thanks,that's great but i really don't want to use any functions like im2col .. i need the whole code be based on mathematics .. as i need to implement this code in verilog so what should i do with im2col ?!

Comment: @abdallahkamal By the way, with this approach for a box size of `4 x 4`. it scales down the image by a factor of 4 along rows and columns. Do you want it that way?

Comment: @abdallahkamal Just edited the code and with it, the downsize factor is `2`. Thus, a `256 x 256` image would be scaled down to `128 x 128`. See if the results work for you?

Comment: @abdallahkamal Also, just replaced `im2cols` with something purely based on mathematics and re-arranging elements and thus you won't need any special toolbox for that.

Comment: sure , i'm averaging 4  pixels

Comment: so grateful .. i'm going to try it